# What is the logic behind EF SaveChanges Method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When I insert a new Item in a DBSet like:

```
var newItemAdded = MyDBSet.Add(itemToAdd);
```

Then I save the changes in the DB like:

```
MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

My variable *newItemAdded* has been updated with the new Id auto generated by the DB.

I went to [EF Core Github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/4b0d9dc416c57368b1cf76e9d76de365cc5e6d9f/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs#L186) to see the logic, but with the big amount of files in the repository, I'm not sure to understand the logic behind.

My concern is more about how the *SaveChanges* executed after the insert could update *newItemAdded*. EF does not seem to use *ref*.

Maybe someone already know how does it work?

Thanks

Comment: What else is there to explain? EF knows which property is the autogenerated key, MySQL allows retrieval of the generated ID (perhaps it's SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() .. haven't looked recently) and EF plumbs the value back..

Comment: Also, I wouldn't guarantee you'd find the answer in the efcore repo; you'd probably have to look at the source of the MySQL provider you're using (and there are a few) - retrieving the generated ID would be a database specific thing (it's certainly different in SQLS, MySQL and Oracle) which means it would be down to the provider to do it. It might be easiest to just turn on logging of every SQL run while your context does its work, and then look at what it runs..

Comment: What I don't undersand is usually when am object is updated outside of the method, it's because we return a ref, so this referenced object will be updated which is not the case there

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding `ref`. `ref` is nothing to do with modifying the data contents contents of some object instance; `ref` permits a method to reassign a variable outside some method so that the variable points to a whole new object. It is absolutely not needed to change e.g. the Name of a Person passed into a method...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but EF does not use ref anyway. But the object newItemAdded is updated still after the savechanges. How to reproduce that?

Comment: `ref` is not "pass by reference", but a lot of people confuse the two, I suspect because (alas) they start with the same 3 letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, without `ref`:

```
class Person{
  int Id {get;set;} = -1; 
  string Name {get;set;}
}

...

void SaveChanges(Person per){     //no ref here
  //simulate saving to DB
  per.Id = new Random().Next();
}

...

var p = new Person{ Name = "John"; }
Console.WriteLine(p.Id); //prints -1;
SaveChanges(p);
Console.WriteLine(p.Id); //prints some random number
```

We never needed `ref` to make sure that the Id of the person set inside SaveChanges survived and was seen by `p` after SaveChanges was done.

Conceptually this is what happens in memory when the SaveChanges code above is called:

```
p --> [ John, -1 ]                 //var p = new Person{Name = "John"}
p --> [ John, -1 ] <-- per         //SaveChanges(p), establishes another variable per, pointing at the same in memory data
p --> [ John, 23 ] <-- per       //per.Id = random number
p --> [ John, 23 ]               //method exits, variable per goes away. p survives and sees changed data
```

`ref` is a mechanism that would allow SaveChanges to swap the passed in Person out for a whole `new` Person. If you had a SaveChanges like:

```
void SaveChanges(Person per){
  per = new Person{ Name = "Jane", Id = 234 }
}
```

Then the objects in memory steps would look like:

```
p --> [ John, -1 ]                             //var p = new Person{Name = "John"}
p --> [ John, -1 ] <-- per                     //SaveChanges(p), establishes another reference called per, pointing at the same in-memory data
p --> [ John, -1 ]     per --> [Sarah, 23]     //per is reassigned to a new Person created elsewhere in memory
p --> [ John, -1 ]                             //method exits, variable per goes away. Sarah is vaporized. John was never changed
```

Suppose we use ref:

```
void SaveChanges(ref Person per){
  per = new ...
}
```

`ref` means `p` and `per` are the same reference. There isn't an additional one made, which could be pointed somewhere else while `p` stayed pointing at John

Imagine that `ref` temporarily renamed `p` to `per` and thus the SaveChanges method doing `per = new Person` also affects `p`. It could be thought of as like:

```
p ---------> [ John, -1 ]                    //var p = new Person{Name = "John"}
per was p -> [ John, -1 ]                    //SaveChanges(p), establishes another variable per, pointing at the same in memory data
per was p -> [ Sarah, 23]                    //per = new Person..., John is lost here
p ---------> [ Sarah, 23]                    //method exits, variable per goes away. p is the only remaining reference,
```

When EF core saves the changes, it doesn't wholesale replace the entity you passed in with a new entity; it modifies some of the data inside the entity. It doesn't need `ref` for your code to see the changes it made

It doesn't even matter that EF is a two step process - you pass your entity into Add, EF stores it in an internal list, when it SaveChanges() it accesses the data via its own reference for it, but because there is only one data and both your variable and EF's list point to the same data, when EF changes the data your variable sees it, because it's the same data at the same memory location